# Datepicker Bug : Using Datepicker seams to mess up with the jQuery on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I've built a form in which I use at some point Datepicker :

```
              <div class="col-lg-5">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="datepicker" style="padding-bottom:10px;">Deadline pour l'étudiant</label>

                  <div class="controls with-icon-over-input">
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input class="form-control hasdatepicker" id="datepicker" name="offer[end_date]" placeholder="31/12/2020" style="border-radius:5px" type="text">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

On the CSS part, I've downloaded  bootstrap-datetimepicker.js, version 4.0.0.

My problem is : every time I start using Datepicker on my footer_application.js file, all the jQuery features stop functioning.

I mean, as soon as I write on my footer_application.js file:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults( $.datepicker.regional[ "fr" ] );
```

The Javascript effect that shows "Sans expliciter le nom, présentez votre entreprise (...)" stops functioning.

[image]

And the Datepicker doesn't seem to apply neither. I'm new to Javascript and jQuery so any help or clue is more than welcome.

And if you need any more information, I'll be more than pleased to add it to this post.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon,

I don't know what language that is, but I'm not familiar with it so I don't know what error you are getting. However, I can tell you that typically this sort of stuff happens when you are doing something syntactically wrong, or that completely breaks the JavaScript. Once this line is attempted to be executed (and, again, this line of code is probably not correct for its purpose), JavaScript stops executing and everything after it does not get ran. I'd recommend double-checking the syntax for exactly what you are trying to do.

Regards,